# Django db_index=True not creating index, but class Meta indexes yes

Tags: django, indexing

In my django model, when creating indexes via db_index=True in field definitions, the index is not created. Only if I created in the class Meta

```
class Agreement(UUIDPrimaryKey):
  job = models.ForeignKey(           
    'posts.Job',                   
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,      
    verbose_name=_("job"),         
  )
  class Meta:
    indexes = (
      models.Index(fields=['job']),
    )
```

And if I run makemigrations, the index is created.

```
Create index agreements__job_id_eb7df0_idx on field(s) job of model agreement
```

But If I change my model to:

```
class Agreement(UUIDPrimaryKey):
  job = models.ForeignKey(           
    'posts.Job',                   
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,      
    verbose_name=_("job"),
    db_index=True,
  )
```

And I run makemigrations, the index is deleted.

```
 Remove index agreements__job_id_eb7df0_idx from agreement
```

Should not be the same both definitions?

**UPDATE**

Documentation says they are the same. Yes both create index.. but if you create indexes in Meta, and do not specify db_index=False in the field definition, **two indexes are created**.

This is before setting db_index=False in the field

```
psql# select indexname from pg_indexes where tablename like 'agreemen%';

                 indexname                  
--------------------------------------------
 agreements__job_id_eb7df0_idx
 agreements_agreement_job_id_id_c26bd828
 agreements_agreement_pkey
```

And after setting db_index=False and running migrations/migrate

```
           indexname           
-------------------------------
 agreements__job_id_eb7df0_idx
 agreements_agreement_pkey
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A database index is automatically created on the ForeignKey. At least so says the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey. So it is not necessary to set `db_index=True` in your ForeignKey field of your model.  The option is still there incase you don't want an index (`db_index=False`).